# Drawing match pairs in image-calculated by KNN and the potential bug in Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I wrote a code that it finds the K closest matches by KNN algorithm. After getting the matMatch and matchIndices I tried to draw the match pairs between two consequence frames.

I feed **matMask** and **matchIndices** into function **Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches** :

```
Image<Bgr, byte> imResult = Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches(imModelCurr, imModel.keyPoints, imObserPrev,imObser.keyPoints, **matchIndices**, new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow), new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.Red), **matMask**, Features2DToolbox.KeypointDrawType.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
```

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.0/document/html/e92d37e6-fe4a-ad09-9304-cd2d2533bfa8.htm but I noticed it gives me back wrong drawing between matching pairs:

[image]

Then I tried to implement such function by myself:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < matMask.Rows; ++i)
        {
            if (**matMask[i, 0]** > 0) 
            {
                int indForCurrFrm = **matchIndices[i, 0]**;
                int indForPrevFrm = i;

                //for frame i-1
                PointF fromFirstFrame = getImgObserved(keyPoints[indForPrevFrm]);

                //for frame i
                PointF NextCorrespondingMatchedFrame = getImModelXY(keyPoints[indForCurrFrm]);

                imColorPrv2.Draw(new CircleF(fromFirstFrame, 5), new Bgr(mtchColor), 3);// for frame i-1
                imColorShow.Draw(new CircleF(NextCorrespondingMatchedFrame, 5), new Bgr(mtchColor), 3); // for frame i

                 // draw line on my own matching
              imResult.Draw(new LineSegment2DF(fromFirstFrame,NextCorrespondingMatchedFrame),new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.FloralWhite),1);

            }
        }
```

and fetch the corresponding pair point coordinates (X,Y) and draw it by myself [ see the results in snapshot].

One the left bottom you could see the matches(shown by white line) and each corresponding pairs with a circle in same color [by my own Function] and on the other side-bottom right , it is the results drawn by DrawMatches function from Emgu.Pay attention that these two functions use the same matMash and matchIndices.

So I was wondering if DrawMatches at EMGU has bugs or I am doing somewhere wrong?

Comment: Please plot fewer points, like 10, it is impossible to analyze the lines. BTW, it is odd that the red dot was not recognized by the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It might be very useful to filter best matches from **matchIndices**, using the euclidean distance between descriptors of each corresponding pair  .
Some times one keypoints from the first image can match well many keypoints from the second image, this can confuse the plotted lines in results.

Filtering could be something like:

```
vector< DMatch > filtered_matches;

 for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_of_model.rows; i++ )
    { 
      if( matchIndices[i].distance < SMALL_THRESHOLD )
          filtered_matches.push_back( matchIndices[i]); 

     }
```